# jQuery selector not returning jQuery object

Tags: jquery

I'm working with jQuery and I have a bit of an issue. I have a bunch of DIVs with a certain class, the first of which I'm trying to select. I can't use the `first-child` pseudo class because of the page layout (long story). But I can get the same effect by treating the jQuery object as an array. My problem is that this does not return a jQuery object but rather a plain Javascript object (specifically a HTMLDivElement).

```
$("#wizard div.collapsible")[0].addClass("selected");
```

That fails because the object returned doesn't have an `addClass` function. It also fails if I use `.get(0)`. However, this *does* work.

```
$($("#wizard div.collapsible")[0]).addClass("selected");
```

Is there a way to do this without have to do the double jQuery selector? (Not that it's a big deal, but it looks kind of confusing.)

Comment: You can also check out `.first()` http://api.jquery.com/first/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what the [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) and [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first) functions do. `eq` obtains an element from a selection by a 0-based index, while `first` just gets the first element from a selection.

```
$("#wizard div.collapsible").eq(0).addClass("selected");
$("#wizard div.collapsible").first().addClass("selected");
```

Interestingly, though, you've actually hit on the fastest way to get a jQuery selection containing the first element from another selection:

```
$($("#wizard div.collapsible")[0]).addClass("selected");
```

It's not a great way to do it, because it's so hard to read and the performance benefits are minimal, but it *is* fastest!

Comment: Not too worried about speed here, just readability. But that's interesting to say the least.

Comment: Also not mentioned is that `[0]` bracket notation will give you the **plain javascript** element, which strips the jQuery from it. Great if you don't need jQuery on it anymore!

Comment: Why does JQuery behave this way? It returns a JQuery object at some places, it does not at the other places... Is there any pattern?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa It returns a jQuery object unless you specifically ask for the native element(s).

Answer (score 2):

`[0]` will be a raw element. That's correct and desired behaviour. If you want to retain the jQuery object, use `$("selector:first")` or `$("selector").first()` or `$("selector").eq(0)` to get the first element wrapped in a jQuery object.

Comment: A million answers, but I like the `first` pseudo class the best. Thank you.

Comment: @GJK The pseudo-class is the worst way to go, because it means jQuery has to do the heavy lifting. Browsers don't natively understand `:first`, so jQuery's selector engine has to do all the work.

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't aware that `:first` wasn't a native CSS selector. I'll probably go with the `first()` function then. Thank you.

Comment: @GJK [It's in the pipeline for Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-nth-match-pseudo), but it's not here yet.

Answer (score 0):

[`$.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) should do the trick:

```
$("#wizard div.collapsible").eq(0).addClass("selected");
```

If you select a class shared by more than one element, a jQuery collection will be returned. Attempting to access that collection as an array will return a raw object, whereas `$.eq` has been designed to return a jQuery object for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
$("#wizard div.collapsible").eq(0).addClass("selected");
```

Or... first()

```
$("#wizard div.collapsible").first().addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$('#wizard div.collapsible')[0]` you return a plain JS object as you said, since it's a plain JS object, and not a jQuery object, you're unable to use jQuery methods on it. You could either use the double selector or use `$('#wizard div.collapsible')[0].className = "selected";`